# how to read data send from renderpartial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, renderpartial

in my index.aspx page i have something like:

```
  <% int tid = Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["TemplateId"]);
  Html.RenderPartial("/Views/Templates/MyModule.aspx", tid); %>
```

how to read tid in MyModule.aspx using javascript
pls help

thanx

Answer (score 1):

Just to have asp.net write the tid out as a javascript variable

```
<% int tid = Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["TemplateId"]);
  Html.RenderPartial("/Views/Templates/MyModule.aspx", tid); %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var tid = <%= tid.ToString() %>
</script>
```

You may want to output this in the head of your HTML.

Comment: Yep this works, you can also set a hidden input with the value, if you don't like the idea of cross language scripting.

Answer (score 1):

I like @Stephen's answer.

Another alternative is to use jQuery like this;

```
Html.RenderPartial("/Views/Templates/MyModule.aspx", tid, new { @class='TID'});
```

then the jQuery

```
var tid = $('.TID').val();
```

I uppercased tid to indicate that TID is the class name as opposed to the value from your model.